# Sharepoint custom List

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have users on the active directory and they all have full control on the sites. But I want to give read only permsissions through my list in my subsite. Which I have done. But still they have full control permsions. How to sort this?

And Also I want to make a field in custom list as editable by admins (only one field.)

any help??

Hari

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more, what exactly have you done which permissions did you change?

Comment: I have list of users on the main site. they have full control on the parent site. I have created a subsite and created a group on that site, and added these users on to the site. I have specifically given read permission on the site and read permission on the custom list. But still they are having full control on the site and custom list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i can think of is that intially you have created a subsite by inheritting the parent site permissions and later on you revoked them. In this case SharePoint Kindly create a subsite which is not inherriting the permissions from the main site and you would be able to resolve the issue

Comment: There is base site which already created by some one. The users are from active directory. These users have full control on the main site. I have created a subsite and added the same users from active directory to my own group, gave read permissions on the group and on the custom list. But Still they have full permission on the subsite and custom list.

Comment: Kindly let answer my first question did you create the subsite by inheriting the permissions from base site or at time of creation you had selected "Use unique permissions"